# Custom column type in cassandra: List of arrays

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, user-defined-types

How can I define a table schema for a custom column type, as described below?

I did look at the [Datastax documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDT.html) for UDTs on frozen types. But, I am not able to apply that to my java code. What changes are required for Cassandra TYPE node, so that I can serialize/deserialize easily?. It should store List of Double arrays in column node.

```
static class Testf {
        String id;
        String name;
        List<Double[]> nodes;
    }
```

Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myks.testf(
id text,
name text,
nodes list<FROZEN<node>>,
PRIMARY KEY (id) );

CREATE TYPE myks.node (
     node map<double>
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way will be to use [ObjectMapper](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.5/manual/object_mapper/) from Java driver.  You can add necessary annotations for your class, and then map class to Cassandra table & back. But you'll need to create a separate class to match your `node` UDT.

Comment: I feel like there is something wrong with TYPE node, Can you suggest how that should look like to have arrays of type Double. Because there is no Array type in cassandra right. Also I will give a try by using ObjectMapper.

Comment: Ah, I missed this... This depends. If you don't need order of entries and only uniq elements, then you can use `set`, otherwise - use `list` (although it's not recommended). If you don't plan to update individual elements using CQL, then it's better to use `frozen` version of all collection types - set, map, list